# How to use LISTAGG with UDT in sql (oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types, listagg

It seems that the LISTAGG function doesn't work with UDT, how can i overcome this problem ?

First, have a look at my sql :

```
create or replace type objtype as object(
    id int,
    col1 varchar2(30),
    col2 float
);

create table myTab(
    col1 objtype
);

insert into myTab values (objtype(1,'col1',10));
insert into myTab values (objtype(2,'col2',20));
insert into myTab values (objtype(3,'col3',3000));

select listagg(t.col1,', ') within group (order by 1) from myTab t;
```

What i want is to show every element of the table in one row, like this :

```
objtype(1,'col1',10) , objtype(2,'col2',20), objtype(3,'col3',3000)
```

But instead i get this error :

> Rapport d'erreur -
>
> Erreur SQL : ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got USER.OBJTYPE
>
> 932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Should i use another function ? what is it then ?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: There is no natual string representation of your collection - although your client might be showing something like what you see as multiple rows when when you query the table. If so that's how the client is interpreting the object; that representation isn't availabel within the DB, so listagg can't use it. The closest you can probably get is a collection of objects, if you can create a matching collection type; and then its display will still depend on your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add function to produce "text" representation of object.

```
create or replace type objtype as object(
    id int,
    col1 varchar2(30),
    col2 float,
    member function toStr return varchar2
);

create or replace type body objtype is
    member function toStr return varchar2 is 
    begin 
      return 'objtype('||self.id||','||col1||','||col2||')';
    end;
end;

select listagg(t.col1.toStr(),', ') within group (order by 1) from myTab t;
```

2) [Create User-defined Aggregates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm#CECEFHHG) - complicated and powerful

ImpAggr is implementing custom aggregation mechanism.

```
create  or replace type  ImpAggr as object(
  list_of_object varchar2(32000), -- second highest value seen so far
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT ImpAggr) 
    return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT ImpAggr, 
    value IN objtype) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN ImpAggr, 
    returnValue OUT varchar2, flags IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT ImpAggr, 
    ctx2 IN ImpAggr) return number
);
/

create or replace type body ImpAggr is 
static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT ImpAggr) 
return number is 
begin

   -- Aggregate Initialize
  sctx := ImpAggr(null);
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT ImpAggr, value IN objtype) return number is
begin
  -- Aggregate Iterate

  self.list_of_object :=list_of_object || ',objtype('||value.id||','||value.col1||','||value.col2||')';

  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN ImpAggr, 
    returnValue OUT varchar2, flags IN number) return number is
begin
  -- retrun result list_of_object.
  returnValue := self.list_of_object;
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT ImpAggr, ctx2 IN ImpAggr) return number is
begin 
  -- merge content only if aggregation process gone in parallel execution
  self.list_of_object := ','||ctx2.list_of_object;
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
end;
/
```

Create aggregation function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomAggregation (input objtype) RETURN varchar2 
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING ImpAggr;
```

And usage.

```
select CustomAggregation(t.col1) from myTab t;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use listagg with your UDT you need to serialize your data somehow. 
From the top of my head you could do as follows to produce an XMLType from your objects and then you could use getStringVal() function on the XML objects - or you could add a toString member function to your objects.

for example:

```
select listagg(xmltype(t.col1).getStringVal(),', ') within group (order by 1) from myTab t;
..... 
<OBJTYPE><ID>1</ID><COL1>col1</COL1><COL2>10</COL2></OBJTYPE>, <OBJTYPE><ID>2</ID><COL1>col2</COL1><COL2>20</COL2></OBJTYPE>, <OBJTYPE><ID>3</ID><COL1>col3</COL1><COL2>3000</COL2></OBJTYPE>
```

or alternatively you can use XMLAGG (with or without getStringVal())

```
select xmlagg(xmltype(t.col1)).getStringVal() from myTab t;
```